# Why linking with imported executable target results in LNK1181: cannot open include file 'xsd.lib'

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm writing my own find module for a third-party application (`xsd` from *codesynthesis*, but I think it's not relevant) and my project needs to use this target in two ways:

- include its headers to build my project
- execute the `xsd` executable to generate sources.

Initially I made the `xsd` target an interface imported library and linking to it with simple `target_link_libraries` was working as expected (my project built fine). Then I went to add the *generate sources* option, so I changed the `xsd` target to an executable, precisely this way:

FindXSD.cmake

```
if(NOT TARGET xsd)
    add_executable(xsd IMPORTED)
    target_include_directories(xsd INTERFACE ${_XSD_INCLUDE_DIR})
    set_target_properties(xsd PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${_XSD_EXECUTABLE}
    add_executable(xsd::xsd ALIAS xsd)
endif()
```

Then I referenced the target this way in one of the libraries (well, it was already like this before I switched from *library* to *executable*):

```
find_package(XSD EXACT ${XSD_PACKAGE_VERSION} REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(my_target PUBLIC xsd::xsd)
```

and the compilation failed as `xsd` headers were not found. I tried to add this to see if it helps:

```
get_target_property(XSD_INCLUDES xsd::xsd INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
target_include_directories(my_target PUBLIC ${XSD_INCLUDES})
```

and now the headers are found correctly, but it fails with

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open include file 'xsd.lib'
```

1. Why does it try to include `.lib`?
2. Why doesn't `target_link_libraries` automatically populate the correct include directories?
3. What is the proper way of handling such dependency?

My motivation to go with an imported executable instead of an imported interface library was so I can use CMake's substitution of `xsd`'s executable path instead of using `XSD_EXECUTABLE` variable outside of the `FindXSD.cmake`.

Comment: `target_link_libraries` may link only with **libraries**. What do you want to achieve by linking with `xsd::xsd` target, which is **executable**?

Comment: I think you probably want a separate target which just exposes the header files rather than trying to link to an executable target